# lubridate date parsing for dates starting with 0

Tags: r, lubridate

I am using the following code to parse dates, but it doesn't seem to work following formats  04 Aug 2017, 05-Aug-2017.  Basically if the date is starting with 0 and we use a number of order formats together as below.
For below example, it throws output as 2014-04-20 UTC

```
library(lubridate)
dateStr <- "04-Apr-2014"
newdate <- parse_date_time(dateStr,orders =c("m d y","m-d-y","m/d/y","d m y","d-m-y","d/m/Y","d B y","d-B-y","d/B/y","B d y","B-d-y","B/d/y","y m d","y d m","y-m-d","y-d-m","y/m/d"),locale = "eng")
newdate
```

Comment: Seems like a better place to report this would be the lubridate issues page: https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues

Comment: Also, why are you trying so many formats? If you use just `parse_date_time(dateStr,orders =c("d-m-y"),locale = "eng")` it seems to work.

Comment: `dmy(dateStr)` also looks good.

Comment: yes it will work if I only put `parse_date_time(dateStr,orders =c("d-m-y"),locale = "eng")`.  However the above code works for 4-Apr-2014  even with all formats. So my query was why it should be different if it is 4 or 04 when the remainder of the string is very obvious Apr-2014..   I needed to put all formats so as to catch different date formats in a large document (10000 pages doc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, more perhaps a side-effect of a "feature".

This comes down to the "relaxed" extensions that `lubridate` supports. For instance, `m` in the strict sense is a month *number*, but `lubridate` also expands to include abbreviated and full month names. Similarly, `y` is typically just the two-digit year, but is extended to include the century as well. (Similar to poly-morphic code, this flexibility comes at a cost: the potential for getting things wrong.)

Further, `lubridate::parse_date_time` tries to be smart by supporting `heterogenuous date-times` (from its man-page), so `"09-01-01"` and `"090101"` will parse to be the same thing.

In this case, since you use `m` and `y`, it tries to go with numeric only, and matches the `14` to `y`, ignores all non-numeric (since you *suggested* numeric), and sees `20` as the day. If you remove all month-leading formatting strings, it no longer tries to find that order of things.

So, mitigation against this problem:

- reduce the number of possible `orders=` formats; the more you offer, the more it can go wrong
- remove all formatting strings that start with `"m"`, only feasible if you are certain your dates will not start with month
- if you have some control over the types of strings you are getting, then restrict the use of numeric-versus-named months, perhaps giving the parser a better shot
- don't use `parse_date_time`, perhaps the other functions (e.g., `dmy` or not-`lubridate`)
- [file a bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues) if you feel strongly enough about this, though you leave yourself open to it when you try "a gazillion" formatting strings

Comment: yes, having both m and y were causing this issue, replacing y with Y does seem to resolve this,  I need different formats as I am parsing a large document and it could contain different date formats.